# Center a WPF Popup inside a Window

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, converters

I have a WPF application and I'm trying to center a popup inside the main window and have it fill the window, but without overflowing the borders. However, the popup appears offset for some reason: [Popup offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLZN8.png). As can be seen in the picture, the popup is low and to the right. Below is my code for the popup and the size converters:

XAML:

```
            <Popup Name="MenuPopup" Closed="MenuPopup_Closing" Placement="Center" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Window1}" IsOpen="False" 
           AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" PopupAnimation="Fade">
            <Grid Name="MenuGrid" MouseDown="Popups_MouseDown"  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Window1, Converter={StaticResource windowHeightConverter}}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Window1,Converter={StaticResource windowWidthConverter}}">
                <controls:MenuView />
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GreyBackgroundColor}" Opacity="{DynamicResource BackgroundOpacity}"/>
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
```

Converters:

```
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double _height = SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight + SystemParameters.ResizeFrameHorizontalBorderHeight;
        return ((double)value - _height);            
    }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double _width = SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth*2;
        return ((double)value - _width);            
    }
```

I can fix the issue by using horizontal and vertical offsets to force the popup into the position, but it seems like a dirty hack that might not work for different windows themes or OS's.

Am I missing something simple, or does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I personally don't like WPF's built-in Popup control, so have [my own custom UserControl](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) for the job. You might be interested in trying something similar if you have issues with the default Popup. But for an issue like this, I'd suggest looking at your application in something like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and see if there's some value you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to get the popup to work Exactly as you want in code:

```
            Popup MenuPopup = (Popup)this.Resources["popup"];
        double dTitleHeight = SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight + SystemParameters.ResizeFrameHorizontalBorderHeight;
        double dVerticalBorderWidth = SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth;
        MenuPopup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Absolute;
        MenuPopup.HorizontalOffset = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)).X - dVerticalBorderWidth *2 ;
        MenuPopup.VerticalOffset = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)).Y - dTitleHeight - dVerticalBorderWidth;
        MenuPopup.Height = this.ActualHeight;
        MenuPopup.Width = this.ActualWidth ;
        MenuPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <local:WindowWidthConverter x:Key="windowWidthConverter" />
    <local:WindowHeightConverter x:Key="windowHeightConverter" />
    <Popup x:Key="popup" IsOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
        <Grid Name="MenuGrid"  >
            <controls:MenuView />
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GreyBackgroundColor}" Opacity="{DynamicResource BackgroundOpacity}"/>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Window.Resources>
```